# Understanding Array of Character String Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, operator-precedence

I a am trying to understand the results I am receiving when referencing the pointer 'p'. I have placed comments in-line, stating what I believe is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char *words[] = { "hello", "world" };
    char **p = words;              // p is now pointing to words[0]?

    ++p; // p now points to "world"

    printf("%s\n", *p);            // Prints the character string 'world', pointed to by p
    printf("%c\n", *p[0]);         // Returns 'w'
    printf("%c\n", *p[1]);         // Should return 'o'? Returns garbage
    printf("%c\n", *++p[0]);       // Returns 'o'?
}
```

My understanding is that after:

```
char **p = words;
```

That *p* now points to the first character pointed to by *words[0]*, i.e., the *'h'* in *'hello'*. Then after:

```
++p
```

*p* now points to the first character pointed to by the pointer at *words[1]*, i.e., the *'w'* in *'world'*.

The results:

```
world
w
<blank space>
o
```

If *p[0] returns the character 'w'. Then, why does *p[1] return garabage? I am trying to understand how the contents pointed to by the pointers in *words is organized in memory, then, where *p* is pointing to after each call.

**Update**

By changing the following lines:

```
    printf("%d\n", *p[0]);         
    printf("%d\n", *p[1]);         
    printf("%d\n", *++p[0]);
```

The results are now:

```
119 // 'w'
1   // 'SOH' -- Start of heading
111 // 'o'
```

Now, what exactly is the SOH character, in this context?

Comment: `p` points to a pointer that points to the `'h'` in `'hello'`.

Comment: So *p[0] references the first character in the array used to store 'hello'? Which is pointed to, by the pointer being pointed to by 'p'? And *p references the pointers itself? Then where is *p[1] referencing?

Comment: `// p now points to "world"` should read: `p` now points to `words[1]`, which points to `"world"`

Comment: `p` points to `words[0]` (and then `words[1]`). `words[0]` points to 'h' (followed by 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0') and `words[1]` points to 'w' (followed by 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\0')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some misunderstanding.

The memory layout after:

```
char *words[] = { "hello", "world" };
```

will look something like:

```
words[0]    words[1]
|           |
v           v
+-----------+-----------+
|   ptr1    |    ptr2   |
+-----------+-----------+


ptr1
+---+---+---+---+---+------+
| h | e | l | l | o | '\0' |
+---+---+---+---+---+------+

ptr2
+---+---+---+---+---+------+
| w | o | r | l | d | '\0' |
+---+---+---+---+---+------+
```

You said:

```
char **p = words;              // p is now pointing to world[0]?
```

If you meant `words[0]`, then you are correct.

You also said,

> That `p` now points to the first character pointed to by `words[0]`

That is not correct. The type of `p` is `char**`. You could say `*p` points to the first character pointed to by `words[0]`.

Regarding the output of the program...

You have a line:

```
++p;
```

This line changes `p` so that it points to `words[1]`.

The line

```
printf("%c\n", *p); // Should return 'w'? But returns garbage
```

is cause for undefined behavior since the type of `*p` is not an `int` that represents a `char`. Type of `*p` is `char*`, not `char`.

The line

```
printf("%c\n", *p[0]);         // Returns 'w'
```

prints `w` since `p[0]` is equal to `ptr2`. As you can see from the memory layout, `*ptr2` evaluates to `'w'`. Hence, you get `w` in the output.

The line

```
printf("%c\n", *p[1]); // Should return 'o'? Returns garbage
```

is also cause for undefined behavior.

Due to operator precedence, `*p[1]` is equivalent to `*(p[1])`, which is equivalent to `*(*(p+1))`. Since `p` already points to `words[1]`, `(p+1)` points to invalid memory.

Comment: I cannot edit your question to fix 1 character, but you wrote this on accident: type of `*p` is `char*`, not `char*`

Comment: Ok. Just for clarification, you said: "You could say *p points to the first character pointed to by words[0]." So after `++p`, _p_ points to the first character pointed to by `words[1]`, i.e. 'w'. If that's the case, shouldn't _*p == *p[0]_? I read _*p_ as; return the value referenced by _*p_. If _*p[0]_ reads, return the value referenced by _ptr2_, shouldn't _*p_ be a synonym for _*p[0]_.

Comment: @crypitc, no, `*p`  is same as `p[0]`, not `*p[0]`.

Comment: Just an aside, how would *++p[0] been written in expanded form? I read that statement as, return ptr2, i.e. p[0], increment it's address by one, then dereference what that new address points too. I see it being written as such; *(++(*p+0)) - which I do not believe is syntactically legal.

Comment: `*++p[0]` is `*++ptr2` is `'o'` with the side effect that `ptr2` now points to `"orld"`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use warning to show you basic error

```
a.c:10:5: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat]
```

`*p` is a pointer to a char.
Try:

```
printf("%s\n", *p); 


printf("%c\n", *p[1]);
```

Here `p[1]` can be the third element of `words` as there is no third element you read garbage value.

For `++p[0]` `p[0]` points to `"world"` with `++` this point to `"orld"` then with `*` you print the first `char` so `o`.

To undrestand pointer you can use `print` with `%p` to see your pointed adress.

Comment: So `printf("%s\n", *p);` prints the character string pointed to by `*p`. But if *p[0] prints 'w', the first char in the array that `*p` points to, why does *p[1] print out garbage?

Comment: @crypitc having done `++p` earlier, `p[1]` would refer to `words[2]` however that is out of bounds for `words`.

Comment: @crypitc I think you should try `(*p)[1]` and `*(p[1])` without the `++p` to understand pointer. `*p[1]` is `*(p[1])`